# ExtJS4 Singleton not a singleton?

Tags: extjs, singleton

In my `app.js` file I have a function named `createPermissions` that goes through an Ext.store called MyAccess and eventually creates a singleton named `UserPermissions` that contains a list of components a user has access to.

This was my original proof of concept code and I decided on Friday on the way home that I wouldn't be able to use a singleton because as each user launched the app it would overwrite and cause everyone's permissions to be looking at the user who last launched the app which is not what I need.

Here is the code:

```
createPermissions: function() {
    var access     = Ext.getStore( 'MyAccess' ),
        components = [];

    access.data.items.forEach( function(permission) {
        components.push( permission.data.id.toLowerCase() );
    });

    Ext.define('UserPermissions', {
        singleton  : true,
        components : components
    });
}
```

In the console after you launch the ExtJS app you can type `UserPermissions.components` and it will output an array of ID's of components the user has access to (this is expected). I had 2 coworkers launch the all also and execute the same command in their console while I re-ran mine and to my surprise, they all remain different which is NOT what I expected (but is exactly what I need...)

So is ExtJS creating a new app for each user that launches the application? That's the only explanation I can come up with as to why each users "UserPermission" singleton would not truly be a singleton, unless the way ExtJS handles a singleton is different than your everyday implementation.

Comment: You mean you and your co-workers launched the app on *different computers*?

Comment: @rixo yes, separate computers.

Comment: @CaleyWoods: the singleton **is** a singleton. Client-side. How did you expect your browsers to magically share data? Yes, extjs creates a new app for each user, inside user's browser. If anything is to be shared, share it server-side.

Answer (score 2):

A singleton is nothing more than a global variable. Now, what is a global variable in javascript?

```
globalVariable = 'foo';
```

really means:

```
window.globalVariables = 'foo';
```

Try it:

```
globalVariable = 'bar';
globalVariable === window.globalVariable; // true
```

Notice we've not even formally assigned `window.globalVariable`...

So, doing:

```
Ext.define('UserPermissions', ...);
```

and later being able to access it this way:

```
UserPermission.components
```

just means that Ext has created a `window.UserPermission` variable for you.

Finally, you probably knows that the `window` object represents the browser tab. So you can easily conclude that you get one "singleton" per browser tab. As far as I know that's what is called a singleton in any language...

ExtJS is just a client-side library, keep in mind it has no server components. So don't expect to find such powerful feature as "flying variables across computers in 3 lines of code without even having to establish connection between them" ^^